# PHP htmlentities json string to android textview text

Tags: java, android

I'm converting json string to display in android textview, I'm using following code in android

My json file look likes,

```
{"managementlist":[{"designation":"PRESIDENT","address":"<strong>Sri<\/strong><br>M\/s.Jewellery Mart<br>No:19\/1, Raghavaiah Road,<br>T.Nagar, Chennai - 600 017.","office":"+91 44 42122288","residence":"+91 44 28341155","centrix":"2159,#421155","fax":"+91 44 42122200","mobile":"+91 9940147199","email":"jayan1411@gmail.com","image":"http:\/\/mydomain.org\/images\/ssss.jpg?1419856154","divider":"0"},{"designation":"VICE PRESIDENT","address":"<strong>Sri Yogesh J Shah<\/strong><br>M\/s. Doimands<br>\r\n "Swarna sree", shop-201,<br># 36\/2,Veerappan Street,<br> Chennai -600 079.","office":"+91 44 25385336","residence":"+91 44 26442978","centrix":"#410024","fax":"+91 44 25387772","mobile":"+91 9382616888","email":"yogesh_shah31@yahoo.co.in","image":"http:\/\/mydomain.org\/images\/Sriyogesh.jpg?1419856154","divider":"0"}]}
```

And my java code looks like,

```
public class Managements {
    private String designation;
    private String address;
    private String officePhone;
    private String residencePhone;
    private String centrixNo;
    private String faxNo;
    private String mobileNo;
    private String email;
    private String image;
    private int header;
get() & set();
}
```

Json Parser:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        for (String line = null; (line = bufferedReader
                                .readLine()) != null;) {
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                        String returnStr = StringEscapeUtils
                                .unescapeJava(builder.toString());

                        String s = returnStr;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);

                        JSONArray membersarray = json
                                .getJSONArray("managementlist");

                        for (int i = 0; i < membersarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject member = membersarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.i("JSON OBJECT :", member.getString("mobile")
                                    + "  ,  " + member.getString("divider"));

                            String designation = member
                                    .getString("designation");
                            String address = member.getString("address");
                            String officePhone = member.getString("office");
                            String residencePhone = member
                                    .getString("residence");
                            String centrixNo = member.getString("centrix");
                            String faxNo = member.getString("fax");
                            String mobileNo = member.getString("mobile");
                            String email = member.getString("email");
                            String image = member.getString("image");
                            int header = member.getInt("divider");

                            list_managements.add(new Managements(designation,
                                    address, officePhone, residencePhone,
                                    centrixNo, faxNo, mobileNo, email, image,
                                    header));

                        }
```

And in my adapter

```
addressView.setText(Html.fromHtml(managements.get(position).getAddress()),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But my list view display the html string as like

```
<strong>Sri <\/strong><br>M\/s.Jewellery Mart<br>No:19\/1, Raghavaiah Road,<br>T.Nagar, Chennai - 600 017
```

This code didn't convert my html string to textview, What is my mistake. Please help anyone.

Comment: No error.Everything is ok in json parser, but problem is in display  my html string as textview text.(Html.fromHtml() didn't work).Display as plain html text in my textview

Comment: yes i had run and got output, but my problem only in html.fromhtml method

Answer (score 0):

you need do script like this

```
// Textview variable
TextView bdeskripsi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ddeskripsi);
// Decode htmlentities
String htmlcodeenti = Html.fromHtml(yourdatajson).toString();
// Decode tag html to webview
bdeskripsi.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlcodeenti));
```